# Shell shows I have mail, but how can I check it

Tags: shell, mailx

When I startup the shell, it displays the message `You have mail.` and this is because I `touch`ed a file `/var/mail/${USER}` and wrote to it.

But how can I check it? I use `mail`, but it shows me `No mail for USERNAME`. And I use `mail -s 'subject' USERNAME <<< 'message'` and it doesn't appear in `/var/mail/USERNAME`. How can I check what my mailpath is, how does `mail` determine, what my mailpath is?

Comment: Did you put a real mail message in there (starting with `From: `), or just junk?

Comment: Junk, I didn't know there was a dedicated format

Answer (score 1):

`mail`, `mailx`, and other MUAs expect `/var/mail/${USER}` to be in [mbox format (RFC 4155)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4155).  I'd imagine their behaviour is undefined when they see data they don't expect, but they may well ignore it, giving you the behaviour you're seeing.

When you try to send mail, the system's mail transport agent (something like sendmail or postfix) will handle its transport.  If incorrectly configured, the message will never arrive.  You might want to look at `root`'s mailbox and `/var/log/mail.log` (or whatever it is on your system).

Answer (score 1):

Show mails in /var/mail/root (${USER} = root, for example):

```
> cat /var/mail/root
From root@tratata.com  Thu May 12 05:05:02 2016
Return-Path: <root@tratata.com>
X-Original-To: root
Delivered-To: root@tratata.com
Received: by tratata.com (Postfix, from userid 0)
    id 5E5351414E1; Thu, 12 May 2016 05:05:02 +0300 (EEST)
From: root@tratata.com (Cron Daemon)
To: root@tratata.com
Subject: Cron <root@webdev> php /webpub/tratata.com/cron.php review
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ANSI_X3.4-1968
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/root>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>
Message-Id: <20160512020502.5E5351414E1@tratata.com>
Date: Thu, 12 May 2016 05:05:02 +0300 (EEST)

PHP Warning:  mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /webpub/wtratata.com/cron.php on line 126
PHP Warning:  mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /webpub/tratata.com/cron.php on line 126
```

Purge messages from /var/mail/root

```
root@hostname:~# > /var/spool/mail/root
```

Do not forget to include the `>` sign, otherwise it won’t work.